# How to configure user mode networking via xml in virt-install

Tags: networking, nat, xml, libvirt, virsh

I want to specify options for user mode networking such as port forwarding, smb share, dhcp, etc... with virt-install. I don't see a way to configure this via command line except for the default basic slirp network. I see it's possible to modify xml of the domain when creating it with --xml. How can I specify user mode netdev options via xml?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.